# SQL: first_value (), getting the min_date for a video

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Happy Friday:

I have a column called view_date. The min value of this date is the date that the video was first put in a specific playlist.

In the same query I am trying to get;

1. the playlist_name,
2. the video_name,
3. min_view_date/ per video/per playlist (when was the video added in
       the specific playlist)
4. the view_date (we later have a filter for
       that in the Where Clause)
5. the sum of views for the specific
           view_date.

I was hoping to use a window function to get the min_view_date.
Here's what I've done so far.

```
Select playlist_name, video_name, 
     first_value (video_name) over(partition by playlist_name order by view_date asc ROWS UNBOUNDED 
     PRECEDING) as min_view_date,
     view_date
     sum(views) as total_views
From t1
Where view_date > '01-Jan-2020'
```

There are many problems with these query: the first value window function makes it so that min value of one of the tracks from the playlist remains the same for all the tracks of the playlist. However I need the actual unique value for each track per playlist.
Also, the Where filter limits my min_dates values. The min_date could be 2016.

**Sample results:**
*Playlist_name*:'A' .....*video_name*:'AHty'...... *min_view_date* = '1-Feb-2017' 
 ......  *view_date=*'7-Jan-2020'  .....  *total_views*=1500

I use Amazon Redshift

Any suggestions?'
Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to mix aggregation functions and window functions:

```
select playlist_name, video_name, 
       min(view_date) as min_view_date,
       min(min(view_date)) over (partition by playlist_name order by view_date asc rows unbounded preceding) as min_view_date,
     view_date
     sum(views) as total_views
from t1
where view_date > '2020-01-01'
group by playlist_name, video_name, view_date;
```

`first_value()` doesn't seem useful here.

Comment: I am trying your method now. See above for sample results. Thanks